# After updating spring-boot repository returns an empty list instead of Optional.empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am updating a spring-boot project from 2.3.3-RELEASE to 2.5.2 atm.
I struggled with some update issues but I was able to solve most of them.

One issue I still got is a test class which checks if a repository has not an entry. It looks like this:

```
@Sql("TestData.sql")
@Transactional
class XRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowired
    private XRepository repository;

    @Test
    void findNoX()
    {
        Optional<List<XEntity>> entries = repository.findAllByAttribute("XYZ");
        assertFalse(entries.isPresent());
    }
```

Repository:

```
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<XEntity, XId>
{
    Optional<XEntity> findByAttribute(String attribut);
}
```

Before the update the test was green but now its red, cause findAllByAttribute returns an empty list instead of an Optional.empty. I played around with the spring-boot versions and this behaviour starts when I update from 2.4.1 -> 2.4.2.

I checked https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.4.2 but I was not able to find the reason why the test fails.

Could anyone give me a hint how I can solve this issue?

Best Regards,
Alex